# Free options to MySQL Query Analyzer

Tags: database, monitoring, mysql

Basically, I'm looking for a free option to [MySQL Query Analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html).

I need a tool that can log all queries and analyze the performance of those queries (time, memory, affected rows, errors and things like these). I have a preference for a GUI tool like Query Analyzer, but fine with a command line tool also.

I intend to use it in a Windows Machine to monitoring a Ubuntu Server with MySQL 5.5.

Anyone knows some tool with these specification?

**UPDATE**

A previous comment (erased) in this question suggested the use of `EXPLAIN`. I didn't know it, but I'll search for more information. If anyone know other tools, they are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one that I know is [TOra](http://torasql.com/), which seems to do what you ask for (and much more).

> TOra is an open-source multi-platform database management GUI that
>   supports accessing most of the common database platforms in use,
>   including Oracle, MySQL, and Postgres, as well as limited support for
>   any target that can be accessed through Qt's ODBC support. TOra has
>   been built for various Linux distributions, Mac OS X, MS Windows, and
>   UNIX platforms.
>
> In addition to regular query and data browsing functionality, it
>   includes several additional tools useful for database administrators
>   and developers – which aims to help the DBA or developer of database
>   application. Features PL/SQL debugger, SQL worksheet with syntax
>   highlighting, DB browser and a comprehensive set of DBA tools.

Here are a few screenshots that could be relevant to you, it's and old version of the program, but you get the idea:

[image: TOra trace]
[image: TOra stat manager]
[image: TOra session]

Comment: I'll test it, but apparently it's perfect! Thx!

Comment: Thanks for this!! It does, indeed, look excellent. Very powerful & feature filled. I was impressed by the quote by the guy from Red Hat who said "It's licensed under the GPL and **it's functionality meets or exceeds the abilities of any proprietary application we've seen**".

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something to help you analyze and optimize queries, the two tools that I can recommend most are [Percona's PMM](https://docs.percona.com/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html) and [Shattered Silicon's SSM (fork of PMM v1)](https://shatteredsilicon.net/mysql-monitoring-ssm/). Both support monitoring of queries via slow log and performance_schema. SSM has a few features that make it slightly better at monitoring RDS instances because it supports query data extraction from RDS via slow log.

PMM only supports query data extraction from performance_schema, which unfortunately doesn't cover information about queries that run as prepared statements, which can be quite a crippling drawback depending on how the application implements it's query execution.